# RSAGA error using rsaga.pisr2

Tags: r, saga, proj

I just downloaded SAGA and the RSAGA package for R.  I would like to use the rsaga.pisr2 function to compute solar radiation for my region of interest.  I am currently getting errors related to proj4 (see below) which I don't know how to resolve.

I set the rsaga environment as follows (for some reason specifying version the first time doesn't work, so I had to do it separately):

```
rse <- rsaga.env(path='/usr/local/Cellar/saga-gis-lts/2.3.2_2/bin/',
                 modules='/usr/local/Cellar/saga-gis-lts/2.3.2_2/lib/saga',
                 version = '2.3.2')
rse$version <- '2.3.2'
```

I converted a raster DEM layer to sgrd format using the RSAGA function rsaga.esri.to.sgrd:

```
dem_sgrd <- rsaga.esri.to.sgrd(in.grids='Documents/IGERT/RockGlacierModeling/GlacierNP/GlacierNP_DEM.asc',
                               out.sgrds=paste0(pisr_folder,'GlacierNP_DEM.sgrd'),env=rse)
dem_sgrd_fn <- paste0(pisr_folder,'GlacierNP_DEM')
```

The original projection of the DEM raster was:

```
 "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
```

I then input the sgrd DEM to the rsaga.pisr2 function as follows:

```
pisr <- rsaga.pisr2(in.dem = dem_sgrd_fn, in.svf.grid = NULL, in.vapour.grid = NULL, in.linke.grid = NULL, out.direct.grid=out_direct_grid_fn, out.diffuse.grid=out_diffuse_grid_fn, out.total.grid=out_total_grid_fn, out.ratio.grid = out_ratio_grid_fn, out.duration = out_duration_fn, out.sunrise=out_sunrise_fn, out.sunset=out_sunset_fn, local.svf = TRUE, location = "grid", latitude = 48.5, unit = "kWh/m2", solconst = 1367, method = "height", hgt.atmosphere = 12000, cmp.pressure = 1013, cmp.water.content = 1.68, cmp.dust = 100, lmp.transmittance = 70, time.range = c(0, 24), time.step = 0.5, start.date = list(day = 1, month = 2, year = 2015), end.date = list(day = 2, month = 2, year = 2015), day.step = 5, env = rse)
```

When I run this function I don't get any output files and I get the following output in the console in R:

```
Error: Proj4 [initialization]: no arguments in initialization list
Error: Could not initialize grid projection.
Error: could not execute tool [pj_proj4].[Geographic Coordinate Grids]
Error: executing tool [Potential Incoming Solar Radiation]


SAGA Version: 2.3.2

library path: /usr/local/Cellar/saga-gis-lts/2.3.2_2/lib/saga/
library name: libta_lighting
library     : Lighting, Visibility
tool        : Potential Incoming Solar Radiation
author      : O.Conrad (c) 2010

Load grid: Documents/IGERT/RockGlacierModeling/GlacierNP/rsaga_pisr/GlacierNP_DEM.sgrd...


Parameters


Grid system: 0.000833; 1719x 1161y; -114.574167x 48.134167y
Elevation: GlacierNP_DEM
Sky View Factor: <not set>
Water Vapour Pressure [mbar]: <not set>
Default: 10.000000
Direct Insolation: Direct Insolation
Diffuse Insolation: Diffuse Insolation
Total Insolation: Total Insolation
Direct to Diffuse Ratio: Direct to Diffuse Ratio
Solar Constant [W / m²]: 1367.000000
Local Sky View Factor: yes
Units: kWh / m2
Shadow: fat
Location: calculate from grid system
Time Period: range of days
Day: 01/01/2015
Last Day: 02/01/2015
Resolution [d]: 5
Time Span [h]: 0.000000; 24.000000
Resolution [h]: 0.500000
Atmospheric Effects: Height of Atmosphere and Vapour Pressure
Height of Atmosphere [m]: 12000.000000

Geographic Coordinate Grids


Parameters


Grid system: 0.000833; 1719x 1161y; -114.574167x 48.134167y
Grid: GlacierNP_DEM
Longitude: Longitude
Latitude: Latitude


source: 
Warning message:
running command ''/usr/local/Cellar/saga-gis-lts/2.3.2_2/bin/saga_cmd' -f=q ta_lighting 'Potential Incoming Solar Radiation' -GRD_DEM 'Documents/IGERT/RockGlacierModeling/GlacierNP/rsaga_pisr/GlacierNP_DEM.sgrd' -GRD_DIRECT 'Documents/IGERT/RockGlacierModeling/GlacierNP/rsaga_pisr/GlacierNP_out_direct_grid.sgrd' -GRD_DIFFUS 'Documents/IGERT/RockGlacierModeling/GlacierNP/rsaga_pisr/GlacierNP_out_diffuse_grid.sgrd' -GRD_TOTAL 'Documents/IGERT/RockGlacierModeling/GlacierNP/rsaga_pisr/GlacierNP_out_total_grid.sgrd' -GRD_RATIO 'Documents/IGERT/RockGlacierModeling/GlacierNP/rsaga_pisr/GlacierNP_out_ratio_grid.sgrd' -GRD_DURATION 'Documents/IGERT/RockGlacierModeling/GlacierNP/rsaga_pisr/GlacierNP_out_duration.sgrd' -GRD_SUNRISE 'Documents/IGERT/RockGlacierModeling/GlacierNP/rsaga_pisr/GlacierNP_out_sunrise.sgrd' -GRD_SUNSET 'Documents/IGERT/RockGlacierModeling/GlacierNP/rsaga_pisr/GlacierNP_out_sunset.sgrd' -UNITS '0' -SOLARCONST '1367' -LOCALSVF 'true' -METHOD '0' -HOUR_STEP '0.5' -LOCATION ... <truncated>
```

I'm running R version 3.40 on a Mac (OS 10.14) with SAGA version 2.3.2.  I have no experience with SAGA or RSAGA.  I ran the code in terminal and was able to successfully output the files I wanted.

Comment: Why do you think it is a problem with proj4? can you run the command directly from the console? The strangest thing I see there is the double bar in `bin//saga_cmd`. You can try specifying the arguments for the [rsaga.env](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RSAGA/versions/1.3.0/topics/rsaga.env) function.

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca Thanks for your ideas.  I've edited my original post to reflect answers to your suggestions.  I deleted a second version of SAGA I had and that removed the double bar you mentioned.  Specifying rsaga.env does not resolve the issue.  I can run the program in terminal, but still no luck in R.  If this can't be easily resolved I may settle for running in terminal, but I would prefer to resolve the issue. I suspected a problem with proj4 due to the first few errors in the output.

Comment: Sorry, I do not have experience in RSAGA. It seems that you need to assign a CRS to the grid? Could you try running before `saga_cmd pj_proj4 0 -CRS_METHOD 0 -CRS_PROJ4 "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0" -GRIDS "GlacierNP_DEM.sgrd"` through a [rsaga.geoprocessor](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RSAGA/versions/1.3.0/topics/rsaga.geoprocessor) function?

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca Good idea.  I was able to assign the CRS in R using: `rsaga.geoprocessor("pj_proj4", 0, list(CRS_METHOD=0, CRS_PROJ4="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0", GRIDS=paste0(pisr_folder,'GlacierNP_DEM.sgrd')),env=rse)`  I was then able to run the rsaga.pisr2 function without error.  If you create an answer I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: I'm glad to know that it worked well. I would prefer if you can add the answer yourself, with the correct code in RSAGA, and accept it. I just thought about how to solve it from SAGA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the suggestions of Gabriel De Luca, the problem was solved by assigning a CRS to the input DEM.  In R:

```
rsaga.geoprocessor("pj_proj4", 0, list(CRS_METHOD=0, CRS_PROJ4="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0", GRIDS=paste0(pisr_folder,'GlacierNP_DEM.sgrd')),env=rse)
```

I was then able to run the rsaga.pisr2 function to calculate solar radiation. For this to work, I also had to make sure to define the rsaga environment, not using the default rsaga.env().